# For loops in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to know how to make for loops in Nim.

This is my code by far

```py
int i = 1
# for loop expected here
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this and other versions of for loops in the [For statement section of the official Nim Tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#control-flow-statements-for-statement):

```
echo "Counting to ten: "
for i in countup(1, 10):
  echo i
# --> Outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 on different lines
```

To find the tutorial, go to main site at https://nim-lang.org/, click on the [learn tab](https://nim-lang.org/learn.html), and finally on the [Tutorial, part 1](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html) link.